# How to add Tabs in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am new to windows phone.Is there any option to add tabs in visual studio for windows phone.In my project I have to add 3 tabs.I can't find an option for adding tabs.If any one knows please help me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using pivot control would be more appropriate for wp7 apps.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941123(v=vs.92).aspx is a good place to start.

To make appealing apps follow design guidelines for windows phone. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637515%28v=VS.92%29.aspx and 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202915(v=VS.92).aspx

AFAIK, there is no tab control for WP7 as it doesn't fit in with the modern Metro look.

Answer (score 2):

Although tabs are not recommended by the default design guidelines, you can still use them if you really want to. Guide [here](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/using-tabcontrol-windows-phone).

[Pivot](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/pivot-applications-windows) or [Panorama](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/panorama-windows-phone-7) would be a much better choice, making the applications more consistent with the system UI.